# Add a security feature to http get request

Tags: java, php, android, security, encryption

I am searching a security function like this:
The user can put his paypal address and an amount of money(which he gained in my app) in my application, and I will recieve it with an http request on my server. Now this is really insecure, anyone with the http requesturl can send me payout data for himself. So what I need is something like a code generator that only my app can create this sort of code, and my php script checks if the code doesnt fit, it wont accept the request. I thougt about java encryption, to encrypt the amount of money. but anybody with the skills to generate a java encrypter can also create an url to send a whitedraw request I think?

I will recieve this result: A text, of my users paypal address, and the amount of money I have to put on his paypal account. this text can and must only be generated by the correct use of my app. So no one can send himself money, he doesnt own.

I saw an app with this function, its called [Plus500](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Plus500) there you can withdraw your money to a(your) paypal account, but I'm not that pro finding out how they do this feature securely.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What will be the end result?

Comment: How did he gain the money inside your app? Is any server side stuff happening to gain the money?

Comment: no. it is only an app side increasing integer. 
he gives me money througt ads, and I'll give him a part of my money back. (short explain)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Plus500 app you are referencing?

Comment: this was just for example
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Plus500&hl=de

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109659/discussion-between-emanuel-graf-and-jonas-koeritz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to generate some kind of proof that the user completed the action you want to pay for. This will require communication to your server (as anything happening on the device can and will be tampered with). This is the reason most apps will not give you real money for viewing ads, they will pay-out some kind of in-app currency only. If you have the possibility to generate such proof, the user can simply present this token to your server on a Pay-Out request.

The Plus500 App is able to keep track of the users funds. Everything is calculated remotely, it's possible for Plus500 to check the plausibility of your funds because you can not earn any money without server interaction.